# Laravel php framework not working well

Tags: php, laravel-5, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed Laravel in ubuntu 14.04, and copied the laravel folder into opt/lampp/htdocs. Then i created : htdocs>laravel2>index.php , where index.php contains:

```
<?php
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function(){
        return 'Hello World';
    });
?>
```

when i go to http://localhost/laravel2/index.php this is thrown:

> Fatal error: Class 'Route' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel2/index.php on line 2

**What should I do to make this work?**

Comment: Did you disabled `'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',` in your  app.php ?

Comment: no, is it needed or detrimental?

Comment: It is needed absolutely !

Comment: how to disable? terminal code?

Comment: You must access the webpage through public folder too: `http://localhost/laravel2/public/index.php`

Comment: Not sure about the terminal code, but if you commented it in your app.php file you need to uncomment it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routes have to go in your `routes.php` file not `index.php`. It's located under:

```
app/Http/routes.php
```

Comment: I didn't get well, a bit more explanation please?

Comment: You don't have to create your own index.php. Put your routes into the file mentioned above and then access the index.php in the public folder. if you have to by `http://localhost/laravel2/public`, but ideally you would create a virtual host that points to the public directory.

Comment: @ParthoProtim You don't have to change the location of `index.php` and you don't even have to create one!! The framework comes with one located in the `public` directory. That's why you need to go to `http://localhost/laravel2/public` in your browser